# How to set ArcMap to view 12 bit tiff

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to view 12-bit tiffs in ArcMap. The problem is ArcMap is forcing the 12 bit images into a 16 bit container. I can set the min/max values to 0-4095 in order to see the 12-bit range. I can do this for each image but that would take forever. Just seeing if there was an easier way to change this. I have found that I can create a layer file with the appropriate min/max symbology, and using [ApplySymbologyFromLayer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm), apply that symbology to every image in the TOC.  However, this is still very time consuming on top of the time required to load my many images.  I have tried running this tool as batch, and through the python window with arcpy.mapping module.

Is there a way to set this type of symbology as default symbology prior to loading rasters into ArcMap?